# Option Price keeps decreasing as the time-steps increase

Tags: simulations, euler, gatheral

I have been writing a code in Python, trying to find a European Benchmark of the Gatheral Double-Mean Reverting model (since there is no available benchmark values online), using the Euler scheme.

For small time-steps (equal to 12, or 20 for example), the Euler scheme is known to give bad approximations. But as the number of time-steps increase, let's say to 500, the Euler scheme should converge.

In my efforts, I notice however that as I increase the number of time-steps (from 12 to 40, and then from 40 to 70, and from 70 to 90) the option price keeps decreasing (it was around 9.5 for 12 time-steps and ended in 8.44 for 90 time-steps). Why does the price keep decreasing? Maybe it will converge somewhere at some point, but why does it have to decrease all the time? Why can it not increase instead? I can provide the code if anyone is interested.

Comment: By converging do you mean it converges to the Black-Scholes price? Why don't you try pricing it with BSM and see if the increase in steps results in the convergence (meaning the decrease in option pricing by Gatheral makes sense).